# Plotting lines without for loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, lines

I am making flow plots for spatial interation models, with x-y coordinates for both origins and destinations:

[image: flows]

The problem is that I keep using nested for loops (one for origins, one for destinations) to plot these lines and am sure there's a better way in R.

Anyway to help answer this question I set-up a simple reproducible example with 4 origins and 2 destinations. Suspect the answer to plotting quicker is in matrix algebra, but not sure where to start. Test it out and please let me know:

```
o <- data.frame(x = c(3,5,6,1), y = c(8,2,3,2))
plot(o)
d <- data.frame(x = c(5,3), y = c(5,3))
points(d, col="red", pch=3)
beta <- 0.6

dist <- matrix(sqrt(c(o[,1] - d[1,1], o[,1] - d[2,1] )^2 +
               c(o[,2] - d[1,2], o[,2] - d[2,2] )^2), ncol = 2)
s <- dist

for(i in 1:nrow(o)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(d)){
    s[i,j] <- exp(-beta * dist[i,j])
  }  
}

for(i in 1:nrow(o)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(d)){
   lines(c(o[i,1], d[j,1]), c(o[i,2], d[j,2]), 
         lwd = 2 * s[i,j] / mean(s))
  }  
}
```

**Edit** - for some context on this project, please see here http://rpubs.com/RobinLovelace/9697

Comment: your first `for` loop can be replaced by `s <- exp(-beta * dist)`

Comment: Ah yes - the first loop is in there as a relic from more complex definitions of s, such as: s <- inc * P[i] * W[j] * exp(-beta * d[i,j]) . Still, imagine there are ways of cutting out loops even here. Any ideas about for the lines though? must be a way!

Comment: Use `segments()` instead of lines?

Answer (score 0):

A way to replace the second loop is to use `mapply`:

```
fun <- function(row.o, row.d)
{
 lines(c(o[row.o,1], d[row.d,1]), c(o[row.o,2], d[row.d,2]), 
         lwd = 2 * s[row.o,row.d] / mean(s))
}

#all combinatios of rows of `d` and `o` 
args.od <- expand.grid(1:nrow(o), 1:nrow(d))

mapply(fun, row.o = args.od[,1], row.d = args.od[,2])
```

The plot:

[image: plot]